# Non-static method startActivity(intent) cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: android

How is it from static context if it's being used within the proper class?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class );
startActivity(intent);
```

full code

```
package com.example.w3_p3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static EditText username;
    static EditText password;
    static Button submit;
    static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = findViewById(R.id.usernameEdit);
        password = findViewById(R.id.passwordEdit);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }

    public static void verifyCredentials(View v) {
        if (username.getText().toString() == "username" && password.getText().toString() == "password") {
            // load next activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            // display incorrect toast
            CharSequence text = "Incorrect Username or Password";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is all taking place within my MainActivity class in a method that is called from a button onClick. Does it need to be called with an Activity.startActivity? All the examples I see just show startActivity(intent); By the way, before anyone gets worried this isn't going live or anything with username and password hardcoded in, it's just for testing. There's no backend or database or anything connected.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the entire class?

Comment: Well I'm already extending AppCompatActivity so shouldn't I have access to startActivity()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is it from static context if it's being used within the proper class?

Because you have the `static` keyword on the method:

```
public static void verifyCredentials(View v)
```

I *strongly* recommend that you remove all occurrences of `static` from this class file. Your four `static` fields are leaking memory, in addition to your problems with your `static` method.

Comment: But doesn't an onClick method need to be static? What is a memory leak? Removing static as you recommended fixed my problem :)

Comment: @swiftthrow: "doesn't an onClick method need to be static?" -- no. In fact, it rarely is `static`. "What is a memory leak?" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak https://stackify.com/memory-leaks-java/ https://www.baeldung.com/java-memory-leaks